# CSS hover with display block on chrome 56

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using a hover effect to show or hide a submenu with CSS. Before version 56 of Google Chrome, it worked pretty fine. With the new version (`Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit)`), however, if your submenu has a scroll bar and you move the mouse over the scrollbar, the hover effects ends. Is there something new on this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        
        li:hover > .wrapper {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Options

            <ul class="wrapper">
                <li>Sub</li>
                <li>Sub 2</li>
                <li>Sub 3</li>
                <li>Sub 4</li>
                <li>Sub 5</li>
                <li>Sub 6</li>
                <li>Sub 7</li>
                <li>Sub 8</li>
                <li>Sub 9</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: This works exactly as you say it should in both Chrome (56) and Chrome Canary (58) - no scroll issues in either.

Comment: It happens also in my Chrome v56. Seems like a Chrome bug to me.

Comment: @AlexMagill MichaelCoker Did you try to hover over the scrollbar?

Comment: @AlexMagill MichaelCoker this version: Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit)   ?

Comment: I am experiencing the bug in Chrome 56.0.2924.76 on Mac OS X 10.11.6.  It only manifests if you hover directly over the scrollbar itself (like your trying to scroll by clicking the bar and dragging).

Comment: @MauricioSipmann I now see what you mean - it does look like a bug to me, not least because if you try the same in dev tools view the behaviour goes away.

Comment: This will be fixed in Chrome 57https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better demonstration of the problem:

```css
.wrapper {
  /*display: none;*/
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #C55;
}

li:hover > .wrapper {
  background: #5C5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Options

    <ul class="wrapper">
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>Sub 2</li>
      <li>Sub 3</li>
      <li>Sub 4</li>
      <li>Sub 5</li>
      <li>Sub 6</li>
      <li>Sub 7</li>
      <li>Sub 8</li>
      <li>Sub 9</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The only way I can see to get around it is to use a custom, webkit scrollbar. use `::-webkit-scrollbar`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`, and `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`.  Not the best solution, but if it's a temporary bug, it may do the trick to hold you over until they fix it.

```css
.wrapper {
  /*display: none;*/
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #C55;
}

li:hover > .wrapper {
  background: #5C5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Options

    <ul class="wrapper">
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>Sub 2</li>
      <li>Sub 3</li>
      <li>Sub 4</li>
      <li>Sub 5</li>
      <li>Sub 6</li>
      <li>Sub 7</li>
      <li>Sub 8</li>
      <li>Sub 9</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a chrome bug. Try modifing the UL line as follows:

**EDITED**
This code works better

`<ul class="wrapper" onmouseenter="this.style.display='block';" onmouseleave="this.style.display='';">`

It is not very clean but it works

My best regards!

Comment: It relies on javascript, but this is a decent solution nonetheless.  I know this question is marked as `html` and `css` to the exclusion of javascript, but this sort of solution shouldn't be inlined in the HTML.  It's generally a bad practice.  Other than that, nice idea.

Comment: because of a personal questions, i can't use JS to solve this. But thanks for the answer